# next button functionality in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which I want to implement the next and previous functionality. User can go forward or backward on stories through this functionality. I have stored current name of story in shared preferences but I am stuck now. I don't have idea of how to read the name of story defined in **string.xml**. So what should I do to implement next/previous functionality.

```
SharedPreferences currentstory = getSharedPreferences("myprefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String currstory= currentstory.getString("currentstory","mystory");
```

In `sharedpreference` I have stored the name of current story. So I will get the name of current story by `getsharedpreferences()` in anther activity. But I want to get the `storyname` of the previous story defined in the `story.xml`.

Comment: Please be clear about what you want to ask. How to navigate through stories or how to read them from xml? Have you tired something yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can read string from string.xml, useing this code:

```
Resources resources = getResources();
final String storyName = resources.getString(R.string.story_name);
SharedPreferences currentstory = getSharedPreferences("myprefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String currstory= currentstory.getString("currentstory", storyName );
```

And save:

```
SharedPreferences currentstory = getSharedPreferences("myprefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = currentstory.editor();
editor.putString("currentstory", "New Story Name");
editor.commit();
editor = null;
```

Comment: in sharedpreference i have stored the name of current story .so i will get the name of current story by getsharedpreferences() in onther activity ..but i want to get the storyname of the previous story defined in the stroy.xml..

Comment: Use string.xml: `<string name="story_1">Story 1 name</string>`, and in activity: `resources.getString(R.string.story_1);`         Or you can define `string-array`, and store in sharedPref index of story in this array. Then `String[] stories = resources.getStringArray(R.array.stories);` and currentStory is `stories[currentIndex]` next and previous: `stories[currentIndex - 1]; stories[currentIndex + 1];`